# Android Multi drawable(assets)

Tags: java, android, drawable, assets, android-assets

I'am looking for a good idea or for a right way to solv a multi  drawable(assets) issue.

From a basic code, i would like to have/generate a multi  app  where the assets are the same but different color.

The assets have the same sizes and the same names. Because of that i can't not put them together. Let us take 2 designs, i call first one dog design and the second one cat design.
I don't want to store the assets of dog design and cat design in the same app but in my project(However) ONLY by generating the APK it'll decide which from dog or cat design will be used.

I hope some already faces this issue. Every suggestion, idea or approach will be welcome

Comment: Are you aware of [Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects)?